# Is it possible to fill a data table from another data table by SQL QUERY in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable

I have a data table (`dtExcelSource`) which is filled from MS_Excel, using `oledb`.
Now I have a second data table, which is structured (`SqlDbType.Structured`).

My requirement is, to fill the second data table with few values from data table(`dtExcelSource`) using query or any other method.

```
 MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO"";")
            MyConnection.Open()
            dtExcelSchema = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
            Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" & SheetName & "A5:F85]", MyConnection)
            DS = New System.Data.DataSet()
            MyCommand.Fill(DS, "SourceTbl")
            dtExcelSource = DS.Tables("SourceTbl")
            'dtExcelSource.Columns(0).DataType = GetType(Integer)
            dtExcelSource.Columns(0).ColumnName = "Serial"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(1).ColumnName = "Document A"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(2).ColumnName = "Contract A"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(3).ColumnName = "Subscriber A"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(4).ColumnName = "Document B"
       Return dtExcelSource
```

My second data table is having 15 columns, so want to insert each rows into second data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your second table have the same structure of your first?
When you said

> My requirement is, to fill the second data table with **few** values from data table(dtExcelSource)

Did you mean you wanted to pull only certain rows from your Source table to copy in to your second table or only certain columns?

Here is something to look at that may help but like I said your post is a little confusing to me.

```
   Private Sub FillSecondDatatable()
            Dim dtExcelSource As New DataTable
            Dim dtSecondTable As New DataTable
            ' Put your code that populates dtExcelSource  in a function that returns the datatable
            dtExcelSource = SomeFunctionCallToYourCode()
            'If something comes back then act on it
            If dtExcelSource IsNot Nothing AndAlso dtExcelSource.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    'I'm cloning your dtEscelSource structure into my
                    'new table because I couldn't understand your 
                    'post completely
                    dtSecondTable = dtExcelSource.Clone
                    'The Select procedure for datatables returns
                    'an array of datarows 
                    Dim arReturnedRows() As DataRow = Nothing
                    'Call Select to filter down to which rows you want
                    arReturnedRows = dtExcelSource.Select("Serial = SomeSerialValue")
                    If arReturnedRows IsNot Nothing AndAlso arReturnedRows.Count > 0 Then
                            'Spin through the returned rows and
                            'import the row into the Second table.
                            '1 row cannot belong to multiple tables so you
                            'can't just add it to the second table while
                            'it belongs to the first table
                            For Each rw As DataRow In arReturnedRows
                                    dtSecondTable.ImportRow(rw)
                            Next
                    End If
            End If
    End Sub
```